# Failed to build docker container for AzerothCore in Windows 10

Tags: docker, azerothcore

I am following the tutorial at https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/install-with-docker but it fails when executing acore.sh docker build with the following message:

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebInfo"
-- Installing: /azerothcore/env/dist/etc/authserver.conf.dist
-- Installing: /azerothcore/env/dist/bin/authserver
CMake Error at src/server/apps/cmake_install.cmake:59 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file
  "/azerothcore/var/build/obj/src/server/apps/authserver" to
  "/azerothcore/env/dist/bin/authserver": Permission denied.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/server/cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
  src/cmake_install.cmake:47 (include)
  cmake_install.cmake:52 (include)
```

Because of that the container doesn't run properly and stays in a start loop forever.

I am building the container in Windows 10 and use the Docker Desktop app. And this is how I download and build the container:

> git clone https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk.git
>
> cd azerothcore-wotlk
>
> cp conf/dist/config.sh conf/config.sh
>
> ./acore.sh docker client-data
>
> ./acore.sh docker build

Please let me know how can I fix this. Been struggling for a couple of days already...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue. Try explicitly setting the owner of the `bin` directory to `acore`.

`$ git diff apps/compiler/includes/functions.sh`

```
    @@ -103,6 +103,7 @@ function comp_compile() {
       comp_ccacheResetStats
    
       time make -j $MTHREADS
    +  sudo chown -R acore:acore /azerothcore/env/dist/bin
       make -j $MTHREADS install
    
       comp_ccacheShowStats
```